# Does google always downrank pages with hidden texts

Tags: seo, google, hidden-text

I'm creating a FAQ for my page. To help the user to get a better overview I want to hide all answers and only display the questions. If the user clicks on a question the answer is set to display:block.

I know that google also reads and indexes hidden content, but I also know that hiding text is a common technique for spammers and thus probably discredited by google, resulting in getting wiped from search results.

But I'm wondering; Does google always downrank pages that have large amounts of hidden text? I mean an FAQ like this is not that uncommon. Should I not use this kind of FAQ?

Comment: This belongs on Pro Webmasters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not be an issue at all. Google doesn't penalize websites because of hidden content. They penalize sites that hide content **for the explicit purpose of manipulating their search engine rankings**. So what you're doing is fine since any user can see that content simply by clicking on a link. In fact, what you're doing is extremely common and even used on the [FAQ page of this website](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).