# Can using div with width = 0px affect SEO?

Tags: css, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does google always downrank pages with hidden texts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/does-google-always-downrank-pages-with-hidden-texts)

Right now I'm working on my new website and I'm really concerned about SEO since the old version of my site(which is from a script that is unusable now) has PR of 4 and I want to lose it
So here is my question
There is a panel that has 4 tabs
Each tabs has  tag which has a href like "/box-page/tab/2" and when javascript is not activated it will go this page and shows the corresponding tab and if it's activated it will just make a simple animation to show the other tab

There are four boxes(and for tabs) and since I needed to fix the height of the panel I had to use width: 0 for the rest of tabs to keep the height of the box the same as the longest one and inside these boxes(which have width: 0) there are some information that can be indexed by google
So as you know google doesn't have javascript and it will go to /box-page/tab/2 and /box-page/tab/3 and ...
in all of these pages the information is the same but with different box showing up in the page
So here is my question
Does google penalize using a div with width: 0px?
And if not does it just ignore the content of the div with width 0?(Which is perfect for me ^^)
Thanks

Comment: There are other similar questions here. Do a search of [seo] and "hidden" and you'll find good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wouldn't know any better than you would, but from here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=1501a761dba0c33d&hl=en

A quick rule of thumb is that the search engines will index everything between the  and  tags that is not itself contained within an HTML tag.  They generally do not consider CSS settings for any purpose other than for detecting attempts to hide text from users.  If you need to serve content in different languages, you should serve that content on discreet URLs.  Good luck!

Sounds like a decent start.